# A composite result based on three variables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've searched the site and I think I have a unique excel question. I'm new to using advanced functions in excel to analyze data. I have a question about how to design a formula to give a composite result between three variables. So the scenarios I'm working with are:

If A=Positive, B =Positive, C= Positive then the overall composite result to be positive.

If A=Negative, B = Positive, C= Positive, the overall composite result to be negative.

If A = Negative, B =Negative, and C=Negative then the overall composite result to be negative.

If A = Positive, B =Negative, C= Positive, then the overall composite result to be positive.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With just the examples you have given us, it's need not be a composite result. The final result is always equal to the result of `A`, so simply `=IF(A1="Positive","Positive","Negative")` would work! Perhaps you need to give a full list of all outcomes or the exact method for determining the outcome?

Comment: If it makes it easier for everyone, I can share a part of the table to illustrate how the spreadsheet is being set up. Being new to this forum I'm not sure what the best approach is for posting/sharing one's work. The table will be de-identified to keep all information private.

Comment: That would be very useful

Answer (score 0):

Are you are looking for a formula something like this one? ...

```
=IF(AND(A1>0,B1>0,C1>0),"Positive",IF(AND(A1<0,B1<0,C1<0),"Negative",IF(OR(A1<0,B1<0),"Negative","ELSE condition when none of the earlier Condition is met")))
```

Comment: After modifying it a bit, this worked perfect for what I needed. My thanks to you all.

Comment: Great!! I am happy that my generic formula suggestion worked with necessary alteration and resolved your problem. Have a Nice time.

Answer (score 0):

From `Digital Logic 101`, you need **8 cases** for an exhaustive list of the all the possible combinations. And that is *if* you ignore the case `0` and suppose it is not present in your data. In that case, you seem looking for something like this:

```
=SIGN(A1*B1*C1) * something
```

or

```
=IF(A1*B1*C1 >=0, "Positive", "negative")
```

Comment: Yes I was going to suggest something like =CHOOSE(4*(A1>=0)+2*(B1>=0)+(C1>=0)+1,"-","","","-","","+","","+")

Comment: I ended up having 8 cases after all for the three scenarios.

Comment: @GStroup and what are those scenarios? is it different than just multiplying the signs?